# how do I get the listview id when the listview is clicked in bloc flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I have successfully displayed the API responses in the listview, but I want when the listview is pressed then I can get the id of the listview item. How do I get the ID ???

I have API responses like the following:

```
"payload": [
{
"id": "402",
"desc": "FAR"
},
{
"id": "406",
"desc": "HGR"
},
{
"id": "403",
"desc": "Baf"
},
]
```

this is the bloc I made :
I am confused how to get the ID when the listview item is clicked, how is it ???

```
class ListMultibillBloc {
  final _repository = EresidenceRepository();
  SharedPreferences sPrefs;
  final BehaviorSubject<List<Payload>> _subject = BehaviorSubject<List<Payload>>();

  listMultibill() async{
    try{
      sPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      ListServiceMultibill  responses = await _repository.listServiceMultibill(sPrefs.getString("userid"), sPrefs.getString("password"), sPrefs.getString("imei"),
          sPrefs.getString("coordinate"), sPrefs.getString("bnr"));

      List<Payload> list = responses.data.payload;

      _subject.sink.add(list);

    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      _subject.sink.add(e);
    }
  }

  dispose(){
    _subject.close();
  }

  BehaviorSubject<List<Payload>> get subject => _subject;

}

final listMultibill = ListMultibillBloc();
```

this is the UI part :
I can display the data list

```
class _ListMultibillState extends State<ListMultibill> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    listMultibill.listMultibill();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: listMultibill.subject,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Payload>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return buildList(snapshot);
            }else{
              Error();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<List<Payload>> snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              snapshot.data[index].desc,
              style: AppTheme.styleSubTitleBlackSmall,
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not fully sure if i understood the question correctly.. but didn't you solved the issue already? if you have access to snapshot.data[index].desc  then you can also access snapshot.data[index].id .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onTap` in ListTile,

```
onTap:() {
     print("${snapshot.data[index].id}");
},
```